# Pandas Join creates unwanted duplicate, only want first instance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have 2 dataframes that I'm joining by their redefined index which is the number we use to identify the study, when I'm joining them they look like this:

**df1 (contains all study numbers):**

| Index | State | PS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | CA | 0 |
| 1002 | NY | 0 |
| 1003 | NJ | 1 |

**df2 (does not contain all study numbers and contains duplicates):**

| Index | Study |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Active |
| 1002 | Active |
| 1002 | Closed |

**I currently have df1 = df1.join(df2) which outputs:**

| Index | State | PS | Study |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | CA | 0 | Active |
| 1002 | NY | 0 | Active |
| 1002 | NY | 0 | Closed |
| 1003 | NJ | 1 |  |

In this example df, I'd like only the first instance of 1002 in df2 to be merged with df1. Assuming it has something to do with 'how' or 'on', but I don't understand the documentation well enough as I am pretty new to Pandas. Thanks!
**Desired output is:**

| Index | State | PS | Study |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | CA | 0 | Active |
| 1002 | NY | 0 | Active |
| 1003 | NJ | 1 |  |

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the first record 1002 is active in the column study or is it true for all entries you define as first instance ?

Comment: Why Active over Closed for 1002?  What is the logic here?

Comment: Not all first instances will have 'Active' (i.e. 1002 1st instance could be Closed, 2nd instance Active, 3rd Instance Active) but I only want the first instance as that is the most recent one. Basically DF2 comes from a data set that is sorted newest to oldest, but with no date.

Comment: @ScottBoston see my above comment. Basically DF2 comes from a 2 column data set that only contains the study # and study status (active or closed). The first instance is the most recent status. It's dumb that there is no date, or the prior instance is not deleted when the status is updated, but I have no control over that. It is only a general log

Comment: @slicedorange7 do approve the solution below if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `drop_duplicates` with `keep="first"` since it is sorted from newest to oldest. Then you merge on the key `Index`

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset="Index", keep="first")
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Index", how="left")
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty much used this same thing except for df2 I used:                                   df2 = df2[~df2.index.duplicated(keep = "first")]

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    'State': ['CA', 'NY', 'NJ'],
    'PS': [0, 0, 1]
}
dict2 = {
    'Study': ['Active', 'Active', 'Closed'],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1, index=[1001, 1002, 1003])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict2, index=[1001, 1002, 1002])

print(df1)
print(df2)

answer = df1.join(df2).drop_duplicates(subset=['State', 'PS'], keep='first')

print(answer)
```

Crucially, the drop_duplicates method should be able to handle this special case